# 5 points on a plane, obtuse angle

Tags: geometry, triangles

There are 5 points on a plane, from which no 3 points are collinear. Proove, that from this points you always can choose 3, which are vertices of obtuse triangle. I already figured out, that they must form a Pentagon, but I cannot come up with ang idea.

Comment: they don't have to form a pentagon, put four points on the corners of a square and the fifth somewhere inside and not on a diagoonal for example

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa They still form a pentagon, just not a convex one, and not a unique one.

Comment: ooops, true. I was thinking totally wrong...:(